# ShareLinkContent .setContentTitle(),.setContentDescription(),.setImageUrl() deprecated

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook for developer site says

> As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.
>   1)a contentTitle that represents the title of the content in the link
>   2)a imageURL, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post
>   3)a contentDescription of the content, usually 2-4 sentences

any alternative way to use this parameter.

Comment: No. Meta tags on the URL that is shared are the only way to set those fields.

Comment: @CBroe how to do with meta tags?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup